# Apollo Client: keeping data from previous query while waiting for next fetching

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I have a `React-Native` component that shows a `map` with markers (`point of interests`). I'm using `Apollo Client` to query those markers from a graphql server. Only markers within the visible map area are returned:

```
const { loading, data, error, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery<
  RectangleQuery,
  RectangleQueryVariables
>(RECTANGLE, {
  variables: { input: rectInput },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
});
```

So every time the visible map area changes (by the user), a new request is triggered and the `React` component renders two times:

- a first time with `{ loading : true, data: [] }`
- a second time with `{ loading : false, data: [...some new data...] }`

**Now my question:** is it possible that the old data in the query is still present in `data` while the new query is loading?

Something like:

- a first time with `{ loading : true, data: [..data from previous query...] }`
- a second time with `{ loading : false, data: [...new data...] }`

As I'm new to Apollo I'm not sure if I can solved it with apollo. I tried several fetchPolicies but none worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the previous data from the query

```
const { loading, data, previousData, error, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery<
  RectangleQuery,
  RectangleQueryVariables
>(RECTANGLE, {
  variables: { input: rectInput },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
});
```

and when you want to show just check

```
const result = loading ? previousData : data
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#previousdata

Comment: In my case, I had to update favorite's list of a user object, so it should only show a loading where the user's favorite's list were displayed.

I used the following line to map over users and avoid flickering ui, when fetching updated users.

const users = data.users || previousData.users || [];